# Last floating image makes <h2> area clickable

Tags: html, css

I've made some links within an `<ul> <li>`. I made images clickable, linking to a new HTML file. I've got four of those, and I wanted to put two beside each other so I used `float:left;`.

However, when I create a new `<h2>` after those images, this `<h2>` becomes clickable and linking to the HTML file used in the last picture.

I've already used `clear:both;` but that doesn't work. Any idea about what may be happening here?

Comment: jsfiddle/demo page please.

Comment: without letting know your code to other its difficult to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `float: left;` on `H2` aswell or `overflow: hidden;` on `li` elements.